# Use key props to force re-render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component where there are draggable components inside with translate applied for the drag&drop and a default translation when it's rendered depending on parent's height and width to keep the ratio.

When I resize the window, the parent component change size so the components inside have to re-render to reset the default translation based on the parent size. I pass the size props to the child's but they do not rerender, I believe this is because the translation is done straight in the style attribute.

So I made a trick to force re-render, I pass the props `key` to the wrapper where the value is the height multiplicate by a width which makes a unique key, change on resizing and then rerender my components with the right default position. Here is what it looks like :

```
render() {
  const { height, width, frame, elem } = this.state;
  const key = height * width;

  return (
    <WrapperFrame>
      <WrapperMediaElem key={frame.id}>
        <WrapperElements key={key} className="droppable" size={{height, width}}>
          <DraggableElement element={{...elem}} size={{height, width}} />
        </WrapperElements>
      </WrapperMediaElem>
    </WrapperFrame>
  );
}
```

This solution works for me but it looks like a "trick" and maybe not the good approach. I wanted to know if it's the right way or if is there a better solution?

Comment: You can overwrite shouldComponentUpdate and return true when height or width changed

Comment: @AvcS I tried this solution but this doesn't work, I think this is because react doesn't update style on re-render

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html
This is how react decides whether it should re render or not, as per the documentation when you are changing style attribute, react should re-render